# NativeScript: app works on emulator, crashing on real device NS7 Angular10

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

After upgrade to NativeScript 7 and Angular 10 app is working fine on xCode emulators but crashing just after run on real device (iPhone 10, iOS14).

TestFlight crash report here:

```
Date/Time:           2020-09-20 12:39:11.5495 +0200
Launch Time:         2020-09-20 12:39:11.1141 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.0 (18A373)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.00.00
Report Version:      104
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x191535114 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:199)
 libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a4d5bcb4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
NativeScript                    0x1055e9428 tns::NativeScriptException::OnUncaughtError(v8::Local<v8::Message>, v8::Local<v8::Value>) + 848
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is TestFlight problem. I had the same problem, after spending a whole afternoon doing 4 or 5 releases it started to work. I did not make any changes to the code, also that afternoon the versions took a long time to be available in the app so I think there was something wrong with TestFlight.